# How to change color and remove underline from text of wx.Hyperlikctrl() in wxPython

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I have hyperlink in my panel.For some cases it should be disabled and the label should be displayed as normal text.

`self.linking = wx.HyperlinkCtrl(self, -1, "", "~")`

To disable the link I used `self.linking.Disable()` and to enable `Enable()` for other cases.

The link is disabled ,but the label still showing as link with underline and 'blue' color.

So I tried some hyperlink methods to set color and remove underline,but couldn't.

Is there a way to do that in wxwidgets?

Please let me know if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the disabled case, just use a `wx.StaticText`. Since wx.HyperlinkCtrl is a hyper link control, it displays as a hyper link.

```
if some_condition:
    link = wx.HyperlinkCtrl(self.window, url="yourlink")
else:
    link = wx.StaticText(self.window, label="yourlink")
```

Comment: @Nithya, are you saying its not creating a label?

Comment: Actually label is creating..But the problem is sizer ..So I couldnt add the staticText into the sizer of hyperlink..Do you have any other idea to add it into  the sizer .Now all the sizers are in one common function. it will be called first and after that label is assigned.